# Cannot start slime with emacs + sbcl under windows

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

I want to configure my emacs to work with SLIME and SBCL. 
The .emacs file looks like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/app/slime/")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Now i'm able to start emacs, but if i type M-x slime, there would be an error complaining something like: "function SWANK-BACKEND: fd-stream-input-buffer-empty-p is undefined" so that the connection to swank fails.

What problem could that be? Thanks

The version of emacs is 23.3.
The version of sbcl is the latest 1.0.55.
Slime is downloaded via cvs.
The operating system is windows7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBCL for Windows is a [port in progress](http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html).

If you want to try out Emacs/SLIME under Windows, you may be more successful with [Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com/). An easy start: try [Lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/), which comes preconfigured with Clozure CL and also includes [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/).

If you really need to use SBCL on Windows, see the [Windows fork](https://github.com/akovalenko/sbcl-win32-threads/wiki) (from the SBCL platform table page - linked to above).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the sbcl_home environment variable works for me with the non-forked version.